# three.j add text / image on loaded jSON object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using https://clara.io/ to create shirt.json for three.js, and then load json by using following code,

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader(manager);

loader.load ('shirt.json', function ( obj ) {

scene.add( obj );

});
```

Here after i need to add dynamic text / image from canvas. How can i achieve it. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried? [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/e6rbt3r4/) is a fiddle that combines 2 images on a canvas and sets it to the texture map of a material. You could use the same sort of technique but write some text on the canvas instead of drawing images.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. But, I need to add dynamic text / image on already loaded object. Please suggest me for this.

Comment: Create a material, create a canvas, write your text / add your image to the canvas, use the canvas as a map on the material, apply the material to the object. Basically the same as what is in the fiddle I linked to.